# python fabric put with dynamic remote_path

Tags: python, fabric

I have two servers that I need to deploy to, but they have a slightly different setup. The application is deployed to a different path on each server (`/var/www/sites/my_site` and `/var/www/my_site`).

My file looks somewhat like this:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'production': ['host1.foo.bar', 'host2.foo.bar']
}

@task
@roles(['production'])
def deploy():
    files = getBundlePaths()

    for file in files:
        # How would I go about uploading to a different path per server?
        put(file, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can setup another variable with the paths and key off that from the current host you are on. Something like this

```
from fabric.api import *

env.roledefs = {
    'production': ['host1.foo.bar', 'host2.foo.bar']
}

env.paths = {
    'production': {
        'host1.foo.bar': '/var/www/sites/my_site',
        'host2.foo.bar': '/var/www/my_site'
    }
}

@task
@roles(['production'])
def deploy():
    files = getBundlePaths()

    path = env.paths[env.effective_roles[0]][env.host]
    print(path)

    for file in files:
        put(file, path)
```